# Collada. Double sided texture do not work

Tags: xml, graphics, collada

I create dae file to export to the web app. My surface has texture only on back (one side of surface). I want it has face and back texture. In collada spec 1.5 (page 26) i see that we should apply semantic attribute with double sided:

```
<input semantic="POSITION" source="#grid-Position"/>
<newparam sid="blah">
<semantic>DOUBLE_SIDED</semantic>
<float>1.0</float>
</newparam>
```

But when i do this nothing changed. I paste this code:

```
<effect name="Material0-fx" id="Material0-fx">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <newparam sid="Image-Material0-surface">
          <surface type="2D">
            <init_from>Image-Material0</init_from>
            <format>A8R8G8B8</format>
          </surface>
        </newparam>
        <newparam sid="Image-Material0-sampler">
          <sampler2D>
            <source>Image-Material0-surface</source>
            <wrap_s>WRAP</wrap_s>
            <wrap_t>WRAP</wrap_t>
            <minfilter>NONE</minfilter>
            <magfilter>NONE</magfilter>
            <mipfilter>NONE</mipfilter>
          </sampler2D>
       </newparam>        
        <newparam>
          <semantic>DOUBLE_SIDED</semantic>
       </newparam>
        <technique id="Material0-fx-COMMON" sid="COMMON">
          <phong>
            <ambient>
              <color>1 1 1 1</color>
            </ambient>
            <diffuse>
              <texture texture="Image-Material0-sampler" texcoord="CHANNEL1" />
            </diffuse>
            <specular>
              <color>0.00784313725490196 0.00784313725490196 0.00784313725490196 1</color>
            </specular>
            <shininess>
              <float>0.3125</float>
            </shininess>
            <transparency>
              <float>0</float>
            </transparency>
          </phong>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
```

What is wrong in my code that texture applied only for back of surface? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In collada spec 1.5 (page 26) i see that we should apply semantic attribute with double sided:

This is not correct. It only gives an example which shows that all semantics must be UPPERCASE, 1.5 spec says:

> Input and parameter semantic names are uppercase. For example, the values for the `<input>` and
>   `<newparam>` elements’ semantic attribute are all uppercase letters:

```
<input semantic="POSITION" source="#grid-Position"/>
<newparam sid="blah">
   <semantic>DOUBLE_SIDED</semantic>
   <float>1.0</float>
</newparam>
```

Your renderer and importer must handle this semantic if you insist to use it. You could also put data in `<extra>` but again importer and renderer must handle it.

Current COLLADA spec[s] does not support double-side attribute directly. For instance if your app supports other formats like glTF then you could write (or modify existing converters e.g. COLLADA2GLTF) converter to convert this **semantic** or **extra** to other format attribute. glTF supports double-sided material. You could convert COLLADA to glTF before use it in web. Or you could only use glTF if you want.

Of course you can use COLLADA in web but your renderer/importer must handle this double-side attribute/element which you put in COLLADA.

PS: Your `<newparam>` usage is not correct too. Because it is not used anywhere. It does not have any **SID** or **ID** attribute which makes other elements hard to access it (if you are not iterating on all **newparam**s linearly and trying to find DOUBLE_SIDED text which is not good idea)